# How to check whether a lagging live stream is the Server or ISP’s fault?

Tags: networking, streaming, buffer, iptv, live-video

I decided to try out IPTV. At times it works fine but very often almost all channels start buffering at random intervals. I want to figure out whether my ISP is to blame or whether it’s the IPTV provider that is actually causing it from an overloaded server.

I’ve tried running background speed and ping tests at the time of buffering and they always seem to be fine. Is there any network or live stream diagnostic tool that would help me with these checks? I always get a 290ms stable ping with the server.

Comment: What's your router model?

Comment: TP-Link WR-941ND

Comment: Is your t.v on wireless? There isn't a way to monitor traffic on this router. Under statistics, you can enable that and record per IP info, but the information available is lacking, and most likely will not help you troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: I would recommend setting up traffic shaping/qos, set your IPtv to the highest priority. Then if you experience issues you can then start troubleshooting your wan, wireless connection etc.

Comment: Yes it’s on wireless and I’ve already set Bandwidth Control. I’ve even tried with a hard wired ethernet connection through my laptop but it still lags. Initially I was also blaming the wireless connection but not anymore because the stream still lags often even when wired.

Comment: What kind of ISP connection do you have? Test your bandwidth at peak-times in your region. If your wan connection tests out ok during peak. I would be pointing the finger towards the IPtv provider.

Comment: I have a 10mbps, fiber to the home. Bandwidth always seems to be as advertised at all times whenever I test it.

Comment: Do you mean megabit or megabyte? If you mean megabit you could be easily maxing your connection if it's hd.

Comment: Megabit. Basically even the normal 480p or 720p channels lag at times. Even the best HD channels use up a max of 8mbps at their peaks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your iptv service. If its not an  authorized trusted paid service and instead one of these fly by night cheap card sharing services you would probably find they overselling there services or using cheap free streams. best way to check is try using another connection like your mobile phone and see if it gives same issues. will let you know more or less where fault is lying

Comment: I use Epicstream which is considered by many to be one of the best providers. Don’t know why it’s causing me issues.